# Disable xss validation (ValidateInput) of action parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Given the following controller & action:

```
    public class CommentsController: AsyncController
    {
            [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(false)]
            public ActionResult AddComment(string subject, string text) {..}
    }
```

When the controller receives an ajax request with `encodeURIComponent("<>")` data:

```
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    subject=hello&text=%3C%3E
```

Then the subject is set properly, but text is always empty.
Why is that?

Comment: Well, I assume I could always disable validation completely with `<pages validateRequest="false">` going back to 2.0 validationMode or encode the string twice on the client and explicitly decode it on the server

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ValidateInput=false`, try to attach [AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute to your input property. It's attachable only to properties, so you'd need to create POCO model for input parameters (btw. in your case it's good practice to have one, for example to have additional validation attributes included). Example:

```
public class CommentModel 
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddComment(CommentModel model) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that way and the `Text` field became `null` when was `<>` passed to it.

Comment: I've recreated your attempt. I've used my example code and performed an AJAX request with following jQuery snippet: `$.post("Edit/AddComment", {subject:'hello', text: '<>', __RequestVerificationToken : '__token__'})` - antiforgery token has been generated through `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on the page. Actually this had worked for me without any problems.